# TypeName vs VarType

Tags: vba, types

I want to check the type of a `Variant`. It is possible to do it with `TypeName` and `VarType`. I guess that using `VarType` is more efficient, since it doesn't involve String comparison, just a numeric comparison. Any reason for preferring `TypeName`?

```
Public Sub testType()
    Dim b() As Double
    Dim a As Variant
    a = b

    Debug.Print TypeName(a) = "Double()" 'True
    Debug.Print VarType(a) = vbArray + vbDouble 'True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**My recommendation**

Use `VarType` for built-in types covered by the `VbVarType` enumeration. Use `TypeName` for other types. I'll explain this recommendation in detail below.

**Performance**

The performance difference is most likely negligible, especially if you use VBA to write database applications.

**VarType**

The big advantage of `VarType` is that it does not use magic strings: If you misspell `vbDouble`, you get a compile time error (assuming that you use `Option Explicit`, which you should). If you misspell `"Double()"`, you code will just silently do the wrong thing.

**TypeName**

The advantage of `TypeName` is that it also works for types which are not covered by the `VbVarType` enumeration:

```
Dim b As New Collection
Dim a As Variant
Set a = b

Debug.Print VarType(a)      ' Prints just the generic vbObject constant
Debug.Print TypeName(a)     ' Prints "Collection"
```

**Gotchas**

Note that if the variable contains an object with a *default property*, `VarType` returns the type of the value contained in the default property instead of `vbObject`. Here is an example using MS Access VBA's TempVar class:

```
TempVars("x") = 123

Dim a As Variant
Set a = TempVars("x")

Debug.Print VarType(a)  ' Prints vbInteger, the type of a.Value's current content.
                        ' (Value is TempVar's default property)

Debug.Print TypeName(a) ' Prints "TempVar"
```

Comment: You're missing the fact that `VarType(object)` returns the type of the object's default property if any while `TypeName(object)` returns the name of the object.

Comment: @FlorentB.: Thanks, I actually did not know that! I have added it to my answer (including a repo example).

Answer (score 1):

TypeName seems more specific when used with objects (such as Ranges or Sheets).

For example with a LastRow function, which you want to call from other vba functions but also from worksheets cells. When passing a sheet name from another cell it directs it as a Range but according to VarType it is a String (**and not an range/object**).

```
Public Function LastRow(ByVal sht As Variant, Optional ByVal colLetter As String = "NoColGiven") As Long
    Dim aSheet As Worksheet
    Select Case TypeName(sht)
        Case "Worksheet" 'VarType 9 (vbObject)
            'call from vba -> LastRow(Sheets(1))
            Set aSheet = sht
        Case "String" 'VarType 8 (vbString)
            'call from vba/ws function -> LastRow("Sheets1")
            Set aSheet = Sheets(sht)
        Case "Range" 'VarType 8 (vbString)
            'call from ws function -> LastRow(A1) where A1 has textvalue "Sheet1"
            Set aSheet = Sheets(sht.Value)
    End Select

    If colLetter = "NoColGiven" Then
        LastRow = aSheet.UsedRange.Rows(aSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row 'last row in whole sheet
    Else
        LastRow = aSheet.Cells(aSheet.Rows.Count, colLetter).End(xlUp).row 'last row in specified column of sheet
    End If
End Function
```