# How to obtain data type directly?

Tags: excel, vba

As far as I know, I can obtain data type using `vartype` function, however it only print out the number and I need to check back the comparable list manually on website to find the actual type, any direct method can show data type immediately such python function type(s)?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `Typename(s)`?

Comment: @Storax Ya, you make my day. Btw, what is the purpose of ``vartype`, it does not make sence if there typename...

Comment: Maybe this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580403/typename-vs-vartype) helps